# How can I add multiple Edge profile icons to the Windows 11 Start menu?

Tags: windows-11, start-menu, microsoft-edge

I use several Edge profiles and I'd like to add them to the Windows 11 Start menu.  'Pin to Start' puts them in the alphabetical list accessed using the 'All apps' button on the Start menu but I want them on the Pinned section of the first pane of the Start menu, ideally in positions 1, 2 and 3 from left.  I've tried dragging and dropping the icons from the desktop.  Is this possible and, if so, how?